# Access subtemplate element

Tags: polymer

I was trying to alter the DOM of my polymer template element from script in the domReady.
Everything works fine in the main template, I can access element using this.$.xxx.
But if the element I want to access is inside a nested template, I can't access it anymore.
[Please see my Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ERPhG1xohjQOgH4laVSw?p=info)

I tought that using this.$.myTemplate.content.querySelector would work (as it works in stand webcomponents apps), but I can't get it to work with polymer

It's not easy to explain, but if you can just open my Plunker, you'll see what I'm trying to do.

Thanks for your help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="polymer@0.5.1" data-semver="0.5.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/polymer/0.5.1/polymer.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <polymer-element name="my-polymer">
      <template>
        <b>TEST</b>
        <template id="myTemp">
          <div id="myID">
            AAA
          </div>
        </template>
      </template>
      <script>
        Polymer({
          domReady: function() {
            console.log(this.$.myID);
            console.log(this.$.myTemp);
            console.log(this.$.myTemp.querySelector('#myID'));
            console.log(this.$.myTemp.content.querySelector('#myID'));
          }

        });
      </script>
    </polymer-element>
    <my-polymer></my-polymer>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [*bind*](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/template.html) the template so it can render it's content: [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/0n9sWZfgNr78Jld2PibE?p=preview)

```
<template id="myTemp" bind>
          <div id="myID">
            AAA
          </div>
</template>
```

Altering the DOM of the template should be avoided if you can solve the problem by updating the template model.
For example bind some object < template  bind="{{ myObj }}" > and then use object's properties inside to alter the template data.

Comment: But, with the bind attribute, the template is always displayed.
What I wanted to do was to alter the DOM of an hidden template tag (<template if=""). I understand why I can't access it with polyer this.$, but why can't I access it with regular DOM script ?